# Windows Phone 8.1 Italic FontStyle Bug?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm encountering strange behavior on a Windows Phone 8.1 project. The culprit is the `FontStyle="Italic"` property of a `TextBox` control.

I created a new Windows Phone 8.1 project, on the MainPage.xaml page I have this XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="Am I mad?"
             FontStyle="Italic"/>
</Grid>
```

On the designer, the text shows in italic:

[image: The designer shows italics]

But when I run the project in the emulator, the italics are gone:

[image: The emulator does not show italics]

I also saw that when I modify the XAML by adding `FontWeight="Bold"` to the `TextBox` like so:

```
<TextBox Text="Am I mad?"
             FontStyle="Italic"
             FontWeight="Bold"/>
```

both the bold font weight and the italics show up and work as expected. Am I missing something obvious?